# Timestamp seconds change when converting from T and Z to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have two timestamps

```
starttime = '2020-10-13T13:42:01Z'
endtime = '2020-10-13T13:42:21Z'
```

When I convert it to datetime, the seconds of the timestamp changes

```
timestampstart = pd.to_datetime(starttime, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ")
timestampend = pd.to_datetime(endtime, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ")

print(timestampstart,timestampend)
2020-10-13 13:42:00.100000 2020-10-13 13:42:02.100000
```

My required output is

```
2020-10-13 13:42:01 2020-10-13 13:42:21
```

What is the problem?
How can I tackle it?

Comment: You have no fractional seconds `%f` in your input strings. In general, you don't need to specify `format` here. The format is pretty standard, ISO8601.

Comment: so i have to just convert to datetime without mentioning format?

Comment: Yes, here you can convert to datetime with just e.g. `pd.to_datetime(starttime)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, your timestamps are formatted according to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The `T` separates date and time, the `Z` stands for "zulu time", i.e. UTC. The correct `strptime` format code would be

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Note that there are no fractional seconds (`%f`) and instead of a literal `Z`, you should use `%z` to convert the Z to UTC. You could also use Python `datetime.fromisoformat` for parsing with a little tweak, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418).

---

***But:*** since the format is standardized and you seem to be working with `pandas`, you can automatically parse as e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('2020-10-13T13:42:01Z')

Out[3]: Timestamp('2020-10-13 13:42:01+0000', tz='UTC')
```